# Are views that include attributes with NULL values updatable?

Tags: sql, database, view

I've read in a textbook that (generally) updatable views are the ones that include PK from the base relation and (possibly) attributes that don't allow NULLs. What is the issue with NULLs? I've tried in MySQL and I am able to update a view with NULLs.

Comment: There's no PK restriction in the ANSI SQL specification. Are you asking about general limitations, or MySQL specificly?

Answer (score 0):

When can a view be updated?
1. The view is defined based on one and only one table.

2. The view must include the PRIMARY KEY of the table based upon which the view has been created.
3. The view should not have any field made out of aggregate functions.
4. The view must not have any DISTINCT clause in its definition.
5. The view must not have any GROUP BY or HAVING clause in its definition.
6. The view must not have any SUBQUERIES in its definitions.
7. If the view you want to update is based upon another view, the later should be updatable.
8. Any of the selected output fields (of the view) must not use constants, strings or value expressions.
   there is noting related to the null value here is an example :

Sample table: agents

```
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| AGENT_CODE | AGENT_NAME           | WORKING_AREA       | COMMISSION | PHONE_NO        | COUNTRY |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| A007       | Ramasundar           | Bangalore          |       0.15 | 077-25814763    |         |
| A003       | Alex                 | London             |       0.13 | 075-12458969    |         |
| A008       | Alford               | New York           |       0.12 | 044-25874365    |         |
| A011       | Ravi Kumar           | Bangalore          |       0.15 | 077-45625874    |         |
| A010       | Santakumar           | Chennai            |       0.14 | 007-22388644    |         |
| A012       | Lucida               | San Jose           |       0.12 | 044-52981425    |         |
| A005       | Anderson             | Brisban            |       0.13 | 045-21447739    |         |
| A001       | Subbarao             | Bangalore          |       0.14 | 077-12346674    |         |
| A002       | Mukesh               | Mumbai             |       0.11 | 029-12358964    |         |
| A006       | McDen                | London             |       0.15 | 078-22255588    |         |
| A004       | Ivan                 | Torento            |       0.15 | 008-22544166    |         |
| A009       | Benjamin             | Hampshair          |       0.11 | 008-22536178    |         |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
```

To update the view 'agentview' with following conditions -

1. 'commission' must be set at .13,
2. 'working_area' must be 'London',

the following SQL statement can be used:

SQL Code:

```
UPDATE agentview
SET commission=.13
WHERE working_area=’London’;
```

In the following topics, we are discussing, that a view can not be updated (using a UPDATE VIEW statement) if any of the fields of the view is created by using an arithmetic expression.

Example:

Sample table: customer

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------+  
|CUST_CODE  | CUST_NAME   | CUST_CITY   | WORKING_AREA | CUST_COUNTRY | GRADE | OPENING_AMT | RECEIVE_AMT | PAYMENT_AMT |OUTSTANDING_AMT| PHONE_NO     | AGENT_CODE |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
| C00013    | Holmes      | London      | London       | UK           |     2 |     6000.00 |     5000.00 |     7000.00 |       4000.00 | BBBBBBB      | A003       |
| C00001    | Micheal     | New York    | New York     | USA          |     2 |     3000.00 |     5000.00 |     2000.00 |       6000.00 | CCCCCCC      | A008       |
| C00020    | Albert      | New York    | New York     | USA          |     3 |     5000.00 |     7000.00 |     6000.00 |       6000.00 | BBBBSBB      | A008       |
| C00025    | Ravindran   | Bangalore   | Bangalore    | India        |     2 |     5000.00 |     7000.00 |     4000.00 |       8000.00 | AVAVAVA      | A011       |
| C00024    | Cook        | London      | London       | UK           |     2 |     4000.00 |     9000.00 |     7000.00 |       6000.00 | FSDDSDF      | A006       |
| C00015    | Stuart      | London      | London       | UK           |     1 |     6000.00 |     8000.00 |     3000.00 |      11000.00 | GFSGERS      | A003       |
| C00002    | Bolt        | New York    | New York     | USA          |     3 |     5000.00 |     7000.00 |     9000.00 |       3000.00 | DDNRDRH      | A008       |
| C00018    | Fleming     | Brisban     | Brisban      | Australia    |     2 |     7000.00 |     7000.00 |     9000.00 |       5000.00 | NHBGVFC      | A005       |
| C00021    | Jacks       | Brisban     | Brisban      | Australia    |     1 |     7000.00 |     7000.00 |     7000.00 |       7000.00 | WERTGDF      | A005       |
| C00019    | Yearannaidu | Chennai     | Chennai      | India        |     1 |     8000.00 |     7000.00 |     7000.00 |       8000.00 | ZZZZBFV      | A010       |
| C00005    | Sasikant    | Mumbai      | Mumbai       | India        |     1 |     7000.00 |    11000.00 |     7000.00 |      11000.00 | 147-25896312 | A002       |
| C00007    | Ramanathan  | Chennai     | Chennai      | India        |     1 |     7000.00 |    11000.00 |     9000.00 |       9000.00 | GHRDWSD      | A010       |
| C00022    | Avinash     | Mumbai      | Mumbai       | India        |     2 |     7000.00 |    11000.00 |     9000.00 |       9000.00 | 113-12345678 | A002       |
| C00004    | Winston     | Brisban     | Brisban      | Australia    |     1 |     5000.00 |     8000.00 |     7000.00 |       6000.00 | AAAAAAA      | A005       |
| C00023    | Karl        | London      | London       | UK           |     0 |     4000.00 |     6000.00 |     7000.00 |       3000.00 | AAAABAA      | A006       |
| C00006    | Shilton     | Torento     | Torento      | Canada       |     1 |    10000.00 |     7000.00 |     6000.00 |      11000.00 | DDDDDDD      | A004       |
| C00010    | Charles     | Hampshair   | Hampshair    | UK           |     3 |     6000.00 |     4000.00 |     5000.00 |       5000.00 | MMMMMMM      | A009       |
| C00017    | Srinivas    | Bangalore   | Bangalore    | India        |     2 |     8000.00 |     4000.00 |     3000.00 |       9000.00 | AAAAAAB      | A007       |
| C00012    | Steven      | San Jose    | San Jose     | USA          |     1 |     5000.00 |     7000.00 |     9000.00 |       3000.00 | KRFYGJK      | A012       |
| C00008    | Karolina    | Torento     | Torento      | Canada       |     1 |     7000.00 |     7000.00 |     9000.00 |       5000.00 | HJKORED      | A004       |
| C00003    | Martin      | Torento     | Torento      | Canada       |     2 |     8000.00 |     7000.00 |     7000.00 |       8000.00 | MJYURFD      | A004       |
| C00009    | Ramesh      | Mumbai      | Mumbai       | India        |     3 |     8000.00 |     7000.00 |     3000.00 |      12000.00 | Phone No     | A002       |
| C00014    | Rangarappa  | Bangalore   | Bangalore    | India        |     2 |     8000.00 |    11000.00 |     7000.00 |      12000.00 | AAAATGF      | A001       |
| C00016    | Venkatpati  | Bangalore   | Bangalore    | India        |     2 |     8000.00 |    11000.00 |     7000.00 |      12000.00 | JRTVFDD      | A007       |
| C00011    | Sundariya   | Chennai     | Chennai      | India        |     3 |     7000.00 |    11000.00 |     7000.00 |      11000.00 | PPHGRTS      | A010       |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
```

This statement bellow creates a view 'myclient':

SQL Code:

```
CREATE VIEW myclient(client_name,client_no,outspercent)
AS SELECT    cust_name,cust_code
outstanding_amt*100/(opening_amt+receive_amt)
FROM customer
WHERE cust_country='USA'
AND  outstanding_amt*100/(opening_amt+receive_amt)>50;
```

To update the view 'myclient' with following condition -

1. 'outspercent' set at 80,

the following SQL statement can be used:

SQL Code:

```
UPDATE myclient SET outspercent=80;
```

but see :

```
This view is a not an updatable view. Arithmetic expression has been used in the definition of the view. So this view is not updatable i.e. the 'view' is read only.
```

Comment: Thanks Ali! Just wondering because I'm reading a textbook that states: "A view with a single defining table is updatable if the view attributes contain
the primary key of the base relation, as well as all attributes with the NOT
NULL constraint that do not have default values specified." Does this mean that views with NULL attributes are not updatable?

Comment: no it means if you have a not null field in your single table which you make your view from it, you couldn't make it null in view with update syntax. if you pay attention to sample one the value for column COUNTRY is null but you can update you view.

Comment: did you get what you need?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but my understanding of the statement is different I guess.

Answer (score 0):

according to your comment I decide to dedicate this answer to null values state in view for insert and update:
NULL Values in Underlying Objects
This restriction applies to insert statements when some NOT NULL columns are contained in the tables or views from which the view is derived.

For example, suppose null values are not allowed in a column of a table that underlies a view. Normally, when you insert new rows through a view, any columns in underlying tables that are not included in the view are given null values. If null values are not allowed in one or more of these columns, no inserts can be allowed through the view.

For example, in this view:

```
create view business_titles 
as select title_id, price, total_sales 
from titles 
where type = "business"
```

Null values are not allowed in the title column of the underlying table titles, so no insert statements can be allowed through business_view. Although the title column does not even exist in the view, its prohibition of null values makes any inserts into the view illegal.

Similarly, if the title_id column has a unique index, updates or inserts that would duplicate any values in the underlying table are rejected, even if the entry does not duplicate any value in the view.
this is from SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise 16.0 
hope you get what you need.

Comment: does this help you?